# fs with authentication on accessing shared directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am using [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) in order to access images from another server, which is in the same local network (but it will soon be moved to different network so that later it will be connected via internet). The point is that to access the shared directory, I need to authenticate in the fs part. It asks for username and password when accessing manually but it does not ask anything when accessing by fs.accessSync(). It just gives me this error.

> Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, access {file path}

So, I am looking for a way to solve this problem. Be it give credentials upon accessing or any other ways.
I tried giving username and password when accessing manually and it will work for a while. After some time, the error will come back again because it needs authorization once more.

UPDATE1: for more information/clarification

It is Windows authentication. It requires username and password. I access it via a local network using file sharing system.

Comment: What kind of remote file system is it and what type of authentication?  Is it Windows auth?  Samba auth?  Something else?

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry. I didn't mention it. It is Windows authentication. It requires username and password. I access it via a local network using sharing system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, my workaround is to provide username and password manually once and make it always remember the credentials. The fs now works as expected without providing any credentials in the fs functions.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, please provide me with details of "provide username and password manually once" !

Comment: Is there a code snippet to pass user credentials while accessing the shared drive?

Comment: Access the shared directory manually via Windows Explorer interface, it will ask for username and password in order to authenticate and if successful it will allow the access. When you entered the credentials, just check the box to make it always remember the credentials. Therefore, the system will remember the authentication and will not ask again via calling via fs.

Comment: @holydragon: How would the code work when its deployed in a cloud server? I would like my "system/service account' to be able to access the NFS